# Image Fields In Sitefinity 8.0

Tags: content-management-system, sitefinity

I get the error with Image Fields in Sitefinity 8.0, the solution is I created a module name Project, it has image field, then I set "Upload 1 Image only" for this field.

So after that I go to the module and add the content image just can up 1 image but after I save the image duplicate. Please help me some ideas.

Comment: That's weird, can you create a short video and show us?

Comment: Hi @Veselin Vasilev, thank for help, after checking the system I see the error is happening when using the "Syncing" from Sitefinity. When syncing the workflow for Image in not correct now, so the solution now I need to create a script and re-mapping the from image library with module.